# Comparing two arrays Ruby and sort

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays, I want the first one to apply the order of the second one so they look exactly the same.

Example

```
array1 = [{name: "grape"}, {name: "apple", {name: "pear"}, {name: "carrot"}]
array2 = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "pear"}, {name: "grape"}, {name: "carrot"}]
```

Wanted result

```
array1 = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "pear"}, {name: "grape"}, {name: "carrot"}]
array2 = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "pear"}, {name: "grape"}, {name: "carrot"}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.I can not copy the array because I am comparing one array in my Database to another that is in a file.

Comment: How about `array1 = array2` then?

Comment: I agree with w0lf. Is there any reason why you're not just copying the array?

Comment: And if you are not copying, you need to define the result you'd wish to have if an item is only present in one of the two lists (e.g. `array1 = [1, 2, 3]`, `array2 = [1, 2, 8, 4]` ) ...

Comment: This is just an example. I really have two arrays of objects that I need to sort by name

Comment: If you want two arrays to sort in the same way, then you can define the sort method using the comparable (<=> operator.) http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html

Comment: OK, so why can you not just do `array1 = array2`?

Comment: Your `array1` is invalid.

Comment: Lol. Thanks. This is just an example though.

Comment: You need to fix your example to something more general. In doing so, don't change what you have, just edit and add text, beginning with something like, "Edit: To clarify my question, here is a second example of `array1` and `array2` and my desired result....". If you don't indicate it's an edit comments or answers may become puzzling or nonsensical. Feel free to use the example in my answer if appropriate. Also, please  add a right parentheses to `{name: "apple",`....

Comment: ... It is important to edit to correct mistakes and clarify your question (as quickly as possible). Even though you've selected an answer, you owe it to those will read your question in future. That would also reduce the chance of additional downvotes and may even cause a downvoter to withdraw their vote. Note votes cannot be changed until the question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array1 = [{name: "grape"}, {name: "apple"}, {name: "pear"}, {name: "carrot"}]
array2 = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "pear"}, {name: "grape"}, {name: "carrot"}]
array1.sort_by { |element| array2.index(element) }
  #=> [{:name=>"apple"}, {:name=>"pear"}, {:name=>"grape"}, {:name=>"carrot"}]
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you, but what if the two arrays don't contain the same elements in each object? I didnt think of that until now. They both do contain "name"

Comment: @user2980169, then use the [block version of Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) that lets you make arbitrary checks.

Comment: This returns `array2`, which is correct for the example, but a roundabout way doing so. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the problem is more interesting than your example. Say we have:

```
array1 = [{name: "grape"}, {name: "fig"}, {name: "apple"},
          {name: "pear"}, {name: "carrot"}]

array2 = [{name: "apple"}, {name: "pear"}, {name: "grape"},
          {name: "kumquat"}, {name: "carrot"}]
```

and want to reorder this `array1` so that all of its elements that are also in `array2` will be ordered as they are in `array2`; that is, `array1` will be converted to:

```
[{name: "apple"}, {name: "fig"}, {name: "pear"},
 {name: "grape"}, {name: "carrot"}]
```

We can do that as follows:

```
arr = array2 & array1
  #=> [{:name=>"apple"}, {:name=>"pear"}, {:name=>"grape"}, {:name=>"carrot"}]
array1.each_with_index { |h,i| arr.insert(i,h) unless array2.include?(h) }
arr
  #=> [{:name=>"apple"}, {:name=>"fig"}, {:name=>"pear"},
  #    {:name=>"grape"}, {:name=>"carrot"}]
```

Note that the method [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) is guaranteed to return the elements of:

```
arr = array2 & array1
```

in the order in which they appear in `array2`.

To improve efficiency, one could replace:

```
array1.each_with_index { |h,i| arr.insert(i,h) unless array2.include?(h) }
```

with:

```
require 'set'
s2 = array2.to_set
array1.each_with_index { |h,i| arr.insert(i,h) unless s2.include?(h) }
```